# Can I run bat file on 64 bit system?

Tags: 64-bit, batch-file

I have a bat file that I ran successfully on my old Windows Vista 32 bit system.

Now that I have upgraded to a 64 bit Windows 7 system, will it be possible to run the same bat file? Is there a difference between 32 bit bat files and 64 bit bat files?

Sorry, bit of a novice at all this.. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

It will *probably* work. Your problem won't be the batch file itself, as the format doesn't change, but may be, for example, the location of other programs it relies on.

In particular, if it relies on something being in `Program Files`, you might find that program has moved to `Program Files (x86)`.

Comment: Also the fact that `Program Files (x86)` has parentheses in it may cause some batch files to fail nicely, especially when blocks are involved :-)

Comment: Shouldn't a batch file use %program

Answer (score 4):

Certainly, you can run a `bat` file in x64 Windows. What you can't run, though, are 16 bit executables.  If your batch script depends on one, you're going to have problems as the batch file will try to run the 16 bit program which will fail.

Answer (score 3):

It will* run ok since it's a script and not compiled.

Edit: It could fail for other reasons - see other people's caveats.

Answer (score 1):

Script is just a list of command line to execute by operating System.. So if the commands in your BAT file are also in Windows7 it will work i think..